# Confused with C# if statements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have very recently started doing coding for Unity in C# after coming from VB.net and i can not seem to figure out after lots of playing around why the code beneath does not work properly. The program is set to begin by playing SquaresLoop1 but it immediately cuts out and the space press is unresponsive.

What I want the program to do is switch between the SquaresLoops on the spacebar press.

```
int state = 0;

void Start()
{
    audio = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"));
    {
        if (state == 0)
        {
            audio.clip = SquaresLoop1;
            audio.Play();
            int state = 1;
        }

        if (state == 1)
        {
            audio.clip = SquaresLoop2;
            audio.Play();
            int state = 0;
        }
    }               
}
```

Comment: You are setting state using a variable scoped to the If statement. int state = 1; does nothing.

Comment: as mentioned by PepitoSh, don't place type before state, its a global variable, and you overwrite it by a local state variable, which disappears when you exit { } scope

Answer (score 3):

Now I'm no expert in `Unity C#`, however I'm almost certain having a semi-colon `;` after your if statement is incorrect syntax - it should **just** be a curly brace.

Try this:

```
int state = 0;

void Start(){
    audio = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")){ // this was the offending line
        if (state == 0){
            audio.clip = SquaresLoop1;
            audio.Play();
            state = 1; // you don't need to re-declare state's type when setting it's value
        } else {
            audio.clip = SquaresLoop2;
            audio.Play();
            state = 0;
        }
    }               
}
```

Comment: I prefer the og post; it's not unity related; we all know it.

Comment: Getting closer. :)  Now the following if statement will always be true and the state will still not flip flop (as I assume was the intention).  Probably just convert the second if to a simple else as a *catch all* instead of checking for the specific `state == 1`.